# Keeping rows with non-english words in Pandas or SQL

Tags: python, mysql, regex, pandas

My dataframe looks something like this on SQL (I can either write my query directly over there or import it in Pandas and then do):

```
videoId    videoName

12234      Racing through the valleys
14533      Character Loose
14456      सूरमा धड़क 
17889      हिचकी
16612      মন তোমাকে ছুঁয়ে দিলাম
15580      ঈশানকোণে বিষন্নতায়
```

So my aspired dataframe would be something like this:

```
videoId    videoName

 14456      सूरमा धड़क 
 17889      हिचकी
 16612      মন তোমাকে ছুঁয়ে দিলাম
 15580      ঈশানকোণে বিষন্নতায়
```

I want to keep the rows with "Hindi" and "Bengali" words. Is there anyway I can do it, directly from SQL or by importing in Pandas, anyway will work.

Then what I want to is differentiate between "Hindi" and "Bengali". Two different dataframes like:

`df_hindi`:

```
    videoId     videoName

     14456      सूरमा धड़क 
     17889      हिचकी
```

`df_bengali`:

```
videoId    videoName

16612      মন তোমাকে ছুঁয়ে দিলাম
15580      ঈশানকোণে বিষন্নতায়
```

As I said, any method will work, but Pandas and Python are more preferable.

Comment: recognizing different languages is not a trivial task. Depending on how constrained your input is though, you can may be able to rely on heuristics. As it stands, I think this is too broad.

Comment: so there is no way, I can differentiate these videos from English, or atleast is there any way I can remove the rows with English characters in the `videoName` column, that will also suffice for now

Comment: You could try several approaches. "english characters" aren't really a thing, do you mean any characters that are in the Roman alphabet, or actuals titles that are in the natural language English?

Comment: You may have to find maximum and minimum limit for ASCII codes of hindi and bengali characters. Then check all the characters fall within this limit

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I want to remove all the rows, having `videoName` in English, that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up [font ranges](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/fontsbyrange.html), Hindi (devanagari) seems to be **U+0900–U+097F**, and Bengali **U+0980–U+09FF**.

```
chars_hindi = [chr(c) for c in range(0x0900, 0x097f)]
chars_bengali = [chr(c) for c in range(0x0980, 0x09ff)]
```

Filtering out the data frames through a regex using [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) gives you the wanted output:

```
df_hindi = df[df.videoName.str.contains('|'.join(chars_hindi))]
df_bengali = df[df.videoName.str.contains('|'.join(chars_bengali))]
```

Be warned though, that this only works given the assumption, that every `videoName` does only contain **either** Hindi **or** Devanagari. If your data cannot hold to that assumption, then you have to solve your problem another way.

Comment: is there a way I can write a query in SQL directly? Because data is huge

Comment: Why didn't you specify this in your original question? You said `Is there anyway I can do it, directly from SQL or by importing in Pandas, anyway will work.`

Comment: yes, yes it works! my bad. Thank you so much. But only problem is even in Hindi Bengali is getting stored

Comment: I don't know how your complete data set looks, therefore I made the comment about the assumption. Maybe you can get the needed results, if you adapt the filter range.

Comment: Another idea might be to make an exclusive match, so you filter by strings that **only** contain Hindi characters and not Bengali ones. Sorry, but I don't know the languages and therefore don't know if they have overlapping characters.

Comment: I have another problem, when I'm exporting the dataframe into a csv, all Hindi letters are gone and weird characters are getting displayed. How can I fix that?

Comment: Ask a separate question. This will keep Stackoverflow more organized. There you should state your OS, because files and their encoding may be specific to it.

Comment: problem solved. When i exported to `.xlsx` all the letters came

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE videoName REGEXP '^(..)*E0A[45]'` will find names in Devanagari (Hindi) text in them.
`WHERE videoName REGEXP '^(..)*E0A[67]'` for Bengali
`WHERE videoName REGEXP '^(..)*E0A[AB]'` for Gujarati
`WHERE videoName NOT REGEXP '^(..)*E0'` would (approximately) avoid any Indian languages.

Selected other languages can be deduced from:

```
| DEVANAGARI LETTER                | E0A485 | E0A4B9 |
| DEVANAGARI SIGN                  | E0A4BD | E0A4BD |
| DEVANAGARI OM                    | E0A590 | E0A590 |
| DEVANAGARI LETTER                | E0A598 | E0A5A1 |
| DEVANAGARI DIGIT                 | E0A5A6 | E0A5AF |
| BENGALI LETTER                   | E0A685 | E0A6B9 |
| BENGALI LETTER                   | E0A79C | E0A7A1 |
| BENGALI DIGIT                    | E0A7A6 | E0A7AF |
| BENGALI LETTER                   | E0A7B0 | E0A7B1 |
| GURMUKHI LETTER                  | E0A885 | E0A8B9 |
| GURMUKHI LETTER                  | E0A999 | E0A99E |
| GURMUKHI DIGIT                   | E0A9A6 | E0A9AF |
| GURMUKHI IRI                     | E0A9B2 | E0A9B4 |
| GUJARATI LETTER                  | E0AA85 | E0AAB9 |
| GUJARATI SIGN                    | E0AABD | E0AABD |
| GUJARATI OM                      | E0AB90 | E0ABA0 |
| GUJARATI DIGIT                   | E0ABA6 | E0ABAF |
| ORIYA LETTER                     | E0AC85 | E0ACB9 |
| ORIYA SIGN                       | E0ACBD | E0ACBD |
| ORIYA LETTER                     | E0AD9C | E0ADA1 |
| ORIYA DIGIT                      | E0ADA6 | E0ADAF |
| TAMIL SIGN                       | E0AE83 | E0AEB9 |
| TAMIL DIGIT                      | E0AFA7 | E0AFAF |
| TELUGU LETTER                    | E0B085 | E0B0B9 |
| TELUGU LETTER                    | E0B1A0 | E0B1A1 |
| TELUGU DIGIT                     | E0B1A6 | E0B1AF |
| KANNADA LETTER                   | E0B285 | E0B2B9 |
| KANNADA LETTER                   | E0B39E | E0B3A1 |
| KANNADA DIGIT                    | E0B3A6 | E0B3AF |
| MALAYALAM LETTER                 | E0B485 | E0B4B9 |
| MALAYALAM LETTER                 | E0B5A0 | E0B5A1 |
| MALAYALAM DIGIT                  | E0B5A6 | E0B5AF |
| SINHALA LETTER                   | E0B685 | E0B786 |
| THAI CHARACTER                   | E0B881 | E0B8B0 |
| THAI CHARACTER                   | E0B8B2 | E0B8B3 |
| THAI CHARACTER                   | E0B980 | E0B986 |
| THAI DIGIT                       | E0B990 | E0B999 |
| LAO LETTER                       | E0BA81 | E0BAB0 |
| LAO VOWEL                        | E0BAB2 | E0BAB3 |
| LAO SEMIVOWEL                    | E0BABD | E0BB86 |
| LAO DIGIT                        | E0BB90 | E0BB99 |
| LAO HO                           | E0BB9C | E0BC80 |
| TIBETAN DIGIT                    | E0BCA0 | E0BCA9 |
| TIBETAN LETTER                   | E0BD80 | E0BDAA |
| TIBETAN SIGN                     | E0BE88 | E0BE8B |
```

Or

```
E0A4xx  DEVANAGARI  ऀँंःऄअआइईउऊऋऌऍऎएऐऑऒओऔकखगघङचछजझञटठडढणतथदधनऩपफबभमयरऱलळऴवशषसह़ऽाि
E0A5xx  ीुूृॄॅॆेैॉॊोौ्ॎॐ॒॑॓॔ॕक़ख़ग़ज़ड़ढ़फ़य़ॠॡॢॣ।॥०१२३४५६७८९॰ॱॲॹॺॻॼॽॾॿ
E0A6xx  BENGALI     ঁংঃঅআইঈউঊঋঌএঐওঔকখগঘঙচছজঝঞটঠডঢণতথদধনপফবভমযরলশষসহ়ঽাি
E0A7xx  ীুূৃৄেৈোৌ্ৎৗড়ঢ়য়ৠৡৢৣ০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯ৰৱ৲৳৴৵৶৷৸৹৺৻
E0A8xx  GURMUKHI    ਁਂਃਅਆਇਈਉਊਏਐਓਔਕਖਗਘਙਚਛਜਝਞਟਠਡਢਣਤਥਦਧਨਪਫਬਭਮਯਰਲਲ਼ਵਸ਼ਸਹ਼ਾਿ
E0A9xx  ੀੁੂੇੈੋੌ੍ੑਖ਼ਗ਼ਜ਼ੜਫ਼੦੧੨੩੪੫੬੭੮੯ੰੱੲੳੴੵ
E0AAxx  GUJARATI    ઁંઃઅઆઇઈઉઊઋઌઍએઐઑઓઔકખગઘઙચછજઝઞટઠડઢણતથદધનપફબભમયરલળવશષસહ઼ઽાિ
E0ABxx  ીુૂૃૄૅેૈૉોૌ્ૐૠૡૢૣ૦૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮૯૱
E0ACxx  ORIYA   ଁଂଃଅଆଇଈଉଊଋଌଏଐଓଔକଖଗଘଙଚଛଜଝଞଟଠଡଢଣତଥଦଧନପଫବଭମଯରଲଳଵଶଷସହ଼ଽାି
E0ADxx  ୀୁୂୃୄେୈୋୌ୍ୖୗଡ଼ଢ଼ୟୠୡୢୣ୦୧୨୩୪୫୬୭୮୯୰ୱ
E0AExx  TAMIL   ஂஃஅஆஇஈஉஊஎஏஐஒஓஔகஙசஜஞடணதநனபமயரறலளழவஶஷஸஹாி
E0AFxx  ீுூெேைொோௌ்ௐௗ௦௧௨௩௪௫௬௭௮௯௰௱௲௳௴௵௶௷௸௹௺
E0B0xx  TELUGU  ఁంఃఅఆఇఈఉఊఋఌఎఏఐఒఓఔకఖగఘఙచఛజఝఞటఠడఢణతథదధనపఫబభమయరఱలళవశషసహఽాి
E0B1xx  ీుూృౄెేైొోౌ్ౕౖౘౙౠౡౢౣ౦౧౨౩౪౫౬౭౮౯౸౹౺౻౼౽౾౿
E0B2xx  KANNADA     ಂಃಅಆಇಈಉಊಋಌಎಏಐಒಓಔಕಖಗಘಙಚಛಜಝಞಟಠಡಢಣತಥದಧನಪಫಬಭಮಯರಱಲಳವಶಷಸಹ಼ಽಾಿ
E0B3xx  ೀುೂೃೄೆೇೈೊೋೌ್ೕೖೞೠೡೢೣ೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯ೱೲ
E0B4xx  MALAYALAM   ംഃഅആഇഈഉഊഋഌഎഏഐഒഓഔകഖഗഘങചഛജഝഞടഠഡഢണതഥദധനപഫബഭമയരറലളഴവശഷസഹഽാി
E0B5xx  ീുൂൃൄെേൈൊോൌ്ൗൠൡൢൣ൦൧൨൩൪൫൬൭൮൯൰൱൲൳൴൵൹ൺൻർൽൾൿ
E0B6xx  SINHALA     ංඃඅආඇඈඉඊඋඌඍඎඏඐඑඒඓඔඕඖකඛගඝඞඟචඡජඣඤඥඦටඨඩඪණඬතථදධනඳපඵබභමඹයරල
E0B7xx  වශෂසහළෆ්ාැෑිීුූෘෙේෛොෝෞෟෲෳ෴
E0B8xx  THAI    กขฃคฅฆงจฉชซฌญฎฏฐฑฒณดตถทธนบปผฝพฟภมยรฤลฦวศษสหฬอฮฯะัาำิีึืฺุู฿
E0B9xx  เแโใไๅๆ็่้๊๋์ํ๎๏๐๑๒๓๔๕๖๗๘๙๚๛
E0BAxx  LAO     ກຂຄງຈຊຍດຕຖທນບປຜຝພຟມຢຣລວສຫອຮຯະັາຳິີຶືຸູົຼຽ
E0BBxx  ເແໂໃໄໆ່້໊໋໌ໍ໐໑໒໓໔໕໖໗໘໙ໜໝ
E0BCxx  TIBETAN     ༀ༁༂༃༄༅༆༇༈༉༊་༌།༎༏༐༑༒༓༔༕༖༗༘༙༚༛༜༝༞༟༠༡༢༣༤༥༦༧༨༩༪༫༬༭༮༯༰༱༲༳༴༵༶༷༸༹༺༻༼༽༾༿
E0BDxx  ཀཁགགྷངཅཆཇཉཊཋཌཌྷཎཏཐདདྷནཔཕབབྷམཙཚཛཛྷཝཞཟའཡརལཤཥསཧཨཀྵཪཫཬཱཱཱིིུུྲྀཷླྀཹེཻོཽཾཿ
E0BExx  ྄ཱྀྀྂྃ྅྆྇ྈྉྊྋྐྑྒྒྷྔྕྖྗྙྚྛྜྜྷྞྟྠྡྡྷྣྤྥྦྦྷྨྩྪྫྫྷྭྮྯྰྱྲླྴྵྶྷྸྐྵྺྻྼ྾྿
E0BFxx  ࿀࿁࿂࿃࿄࿅࿆࿇࿈࿉࿊࿋࿌࿎࿏࿐࿑࿒࿓࿔࿕࿖࿗࿘
```